# Argument of type '() => JQuery' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => boolean'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to write a jasmine test case for my method, but I am facing an error:

> spec.ts(163,18): error TS2345: Argument of type '() => JQuery' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => boolean'.

Can you guys tell me how to fix it?  Providing my code and test case below

```
$('.triggerKPopUpClick').click(function() {
    if ($('#financialDocumentsGrid').data("kendoGrid")) {
        $('#financialDocumentsGrid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data([])
    }
    that.ContractInfoPopUpWindow.data("kendoWindow").close();
    $("html, body").css("overflow", "");
});

it('triggerKPopUpClick in head', function() {
    $('.triggerKPopUpClick').trigger('click');

    waitsFor(function() {
        return $('financialDocumentsGrid').contains('financialDocumentsGrid');
    }, 'theme switcher never loaded', 10000);
});
```

Comment: It should probably be `return $('#financialDocumentsGrid')...`

Comment: @James thanks for your reply..its so confusing...can you update in the code

Comment: In the waitsFor call.  You missed a #

Comment: @James but I am getting an error like this now :(  error TS2339: Property 'contains' does not exist on type 'JQuery'

Answer (score 0):

The [`.contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) method checks if an element is a descendant of another one.

Syntax is `$.contains(parent, child)`. Returns `true` or `false`.

Check your `#` and `.` on selectors too...

---

**EDIT**

Here is an example with your code...
Notice that the elements needed for `.contains()` arguments *must* be DOM elements, not jQuery elements. That is why there is some `[0]`.

```
it('triggerKPopUpClick in head', function() {
  $('.triggerKPopUpClick').trigger('click');

  waitsFor(function() {
    return $.contains('$(#financialDocumentsGrid)[0]', ' $(#AnotherElementWhichShouldBeAChild)[0]');
  }, 'theme switcher never loaded', 10000);
});
```

Here's an example in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/jLZjox?editors=1111).

---

So... That is aout [`.contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) *"special"* syntax.
You noticed that DOM element have to be sent to `.contains` argument as **strings** ?

Maybe you be interested in an alternative:

```
$("#parent").find("#child").length > 0
```

If there's an element having `#child` in the element `#parent`, that is also `true`.